# Change the text field size in Sugar Pro

Tags: php, jquery, backbone.js, sugarcrm

I'm working on SugarPro-7.5, where I need to change the email field size through custom code. I did this in sugar ce but I don't know how to do it in SugarPro.

How can I change text field size ?

Answer (score -1):

Not a very elegant solution:

Copy `clients/base/fields/email/edit.hbs` to `custom/clients/base/fields/email/edit.hbs`

Add

```
<style>
    .email-wide {
        width: 150% !important;
    }
</style>
```

Then add the email-wide class to the input

```
<input type="text" class="newEmail input-append email-wide" maxlength="{{def.len}}" placeholder="{{str "LBL_EMAIL_ADD"}}"{{#if def.tabindex}} tabindex="{{def.tabindex}}"{{/if}}>
```

Run a Repair & Rebuild.

Comment: I followed you'r steps, the text box size is also changed, After that that text box size is changed back to its original state when I press enter (that means the class is changed to '**existingAddress**'). And also I specified the css for the edit-email-field.hbs, nothing is happening.